# Error 1004 Subject not in Worksheet function

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wksSubjectArea As Worksheet
Dim wksFilter As Worksheet
Dim strSubArea As String

Set wksSubjectArea = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3)
Set wksFilter = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(4)

Sheet4.cmbFilter.Clear

wksSubjectArea.Select    -Error Line
wksSubjectArea.Range("F2").Select 

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    strSubArea = ActiveCell
    wksFilter.Select
    Sheet4.cmbFilter.AddItem strSubArea
    wksSubjectArea.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

Sheet4.cmbFilter.Text = ""
```

This is in the "ThisWorkBook" page, i have been getting an error and cannot resolve it. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You assumed that the workbook you are opening is the first one in the collection of `Workbooks` which could be not true. Assuming, that your `wksSubjectArea` and `wksFilter` are both in just opening workbook change the following lines:

```
Set wksSubjectArea = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3)
Set wksFilter = Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(4)
```

into these ones:

```
Set wksSubjectArea = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Set wksFilter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
```

Additionally, but not necessarily, you could use `.Activate` instead of `.Select` in your error line.